# check if a csv file is null or not in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to check if .csv is `null` or not. If not `null` and contains record then process the file otherwise exit. Is there a way to check in Spark Scala code if file is empty or not?

Comment: null isn't a well defined word for a file. What do you mean by it ? I gather it may mean exist/doesn't exist, is empty/is not empty, or maybe something else ?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you want to check if the csv file exists.

If it's on the local system you just use java library:

```scala
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
Files.exists(Paths.get("yourPath/file.csv"))
```

if the CSV is on HDFS then:

```scala
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf)
val exists = fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/path/on/hdfs/to/your.csv"))
```

Comment: its checks only for the existence file, not if a file is null or not

Answer (score 1):

Read that file into a dataframe

`Val df = spark.read.csv("filename")
df.rdd.isEmpty`